# Can't create superuser on Django 1.8 using python 3.2

Tags: python, django

Hello i'm someone new to python, django and programming. 
While trying to create a app with Django, i'm following the website's tutorial and i can ##

Run the command for creating a superuser but everytime i try to insert the requested name it gives me this error:

```
"Error: Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.
Username (leave blank to use 'joao'):"
```

Yes, it keeps showing this error everytime 
Can someone help?

Models.url

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 things - what does the models you show have to do with the `createsuperuser` command? Also, clearly you are either entering `''`, or leaving it blank..

Comment: Thank you very much! But from what i can realize i'm only typing letters and everytime i set enter it shows this very error.

Comment: what happens if you just hit enter without any characters ?

Comment: I get the same error if i do so.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. You can enter only letters, numbers and specified characters while creating a superuser. It has got nothing to do with your Models.

Comment: ok thank you! but can you tell me why i cannot type in letters or numbers?

Comment: Can you tell me the command that you entered to create the superuser and also the name you're trying to set as the username?

Comment: this is the command: python manage.py createsuperuser   || Thank you

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with encoding. Try this. Let's say you want to set admin as your username, then enter this.. u'admin' . See if that works.